# Authorize.net not accepting any testing Credit card on Magento 2.2.5 in sandbox mode

Tags: magento2, validation, authorize.net

I have managed to successfully configure authorize.net with latest SHA on Magento 2.2.5 and its appearing as payment method but when i enter credit card no. it gives error saying
"Please enter a valid credit card type number"

**Using**:
Authorize.net : sandbox account 
CC details: Tried all test CC's given

Seems like validator.js is throwing this error but not sure why it is not accepting.
Even tried applying luma theme in order to check theme conflicts.

Any help much appreciated,

Thanks,
Siddhesh

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing similar issue. Did you get solution to this?

Comment: Not yet but there are 3rd party modules suggested

Comment: yes paid module can get the soultion but from scratch